# Python MySQLdb query returns error when quotes added to the arguments

Tags: python, mysql

I am running the following code, which gives me an error

```
import MySQLdb as mdb

source_sentence = "%Barack Obama%"
filterquery = ""
try:
    con = mdb.connect(MYSQL_HOST, MYSQL_USER, MYSQL_PASSWORD, MYSQL_DB)
    cur = con.cursor()

    print "SELECT sentence_id FROM translation_all WHERE source_sentence LIKE '%s' %s ORDER BY id" % (source_sentence, filterquery)
    cur.execute("SELECT sentence_id FROM translation_all WHERE source_sentence LIKE '%s' %s ORDER BY id", (source_sentence, filterquery))

    uid = cur.fetchone()
    print uid
except mdb.Error, e:
    print "Error %d: %s" % (e.args[0],e.args[1])
    sys.exit(1)
finally:    
    if con:    
        con.close()
```

The error is the following:

```
SELECT sentence_id FROM translation_all WHERE source_sentence LIKE '%Barack Obama%'  ORDER BY id
Error 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '%Barack Obama%'' '' ORDER BY id' at line 1
```

If I replace single quotes with double ones at the query, there is no error, but an empty query is given

```
SELECT sentence_id FROM translation_all WHERE source_sentence LIKE "%Barack Obama%"  ORDER BY id
None
```

Funnily enough, both queries above, return results when executed directly on mysql through commandline or phpmyadmin. Do you have any idea why this may be failing?

Comment: The error doesn't match the query. Are you sure you're looking at the correct query? If you see yourself you'll find that in the error message there is `''` empty string right before `ORDER BY` and there is no one in the "original" query. So I recommend triple check the query and the correspondent error

Comment: Yes, that was my observation as well. But when I change the code in the query, the error disappears. So it is the correct query. The only explanation I have, is that something works wrong with the Python MySQL connector

Comment: I'm not sure it's not possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you're passing parameters to `cur.execute`, the dbapi already does the quoting for you. That means don't use:

```
... LIKE '%s' %s ORDER BY id
```

but

```
... LIKE %s ORDER BY id
```

You'll notice that i've removed the second `%s` as it's an error having it here. When it's substituted with `''` the query doesn't make sense.

Don't let yourself be fooled by the string that is printed before executing the query. That isn't the query that gets executed:

```
"... %s" % ('spam',)
```

does something completely different to a query then:

```
cursor.execute("... %s", ('spam',))
```

Comment: Thanks, this may be the right solution, I am checking it right now. But I still wonder. How can one see the query that is actually executed?

Comment: goot question, actually. [`dbapi2`](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249) doesn't specify anything about that, so it depends on the implementing library. `MySQLdb` does something like: `query % connection.literal(params)`, `mysql.connector` uses `query % cursor._process_params(params)`...